# General safety of aromatic vs. aliphatic hydrocarbon solvents

Tags: aromatic-compounds, solvents

I am not a chemist and I could use some help from those who know. I am wondering about some properties of hydrocarbon solvents that are commonly used for degreasing in other fields. It seems many of the commonly available aliphatics with >40degC flashpoints have Kauri-Butanol values in the 30's. Aromatics (like those advertised as high flash aromatic napthas) in the C9-C10 range with >40degC flashpoints have Kauri-Butanol values in the 90's. Aliphatics are much more commonly used in this role.

My questions:

Assuming there is minimal benzene and VOC's are not a consideration (closed system)

Are the C9-C10 range aromatics (high flash aromatic naphthas) inherently more dangerous than the aliphatics of similar flash point range (mineral spirits)? I know they are more irritating short term in terms of odor and the like, but are they actually more toxic?

Would you expect greater performance of aromatics vs. aliphatics in degreasing tasks based on the Kauri-Butanol values?

Thank you!

Comment: Generally, yes.  But it's something that can be minimized with safety precautions such as good ventilation.  A xylene dip, followed by a warm caustic bath works very well for alkyd resin synthesis glassware.  (Wear long gloves and safety goggles).

Comment: Thank you for the response Robert. Advice taken.